# What is purpose of -ms in css in display property

Tags: html, css, frontend

Came across display:-ms-grid; property.
What is the significance of the -ms.

```
display: -ms-grid;
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Vendor_Prefix

Answer (score 1):

`-ms-` is a vendor prefix for browsers by **M**icro**s**oft (e.g, Internet Explorer and Microsoft Edge), just like `-moz-` in Firefox or `-o-` in Opera.

> Browser vendors sometimes add prefixes to experimental or nonstandard CSS properties and JavaScript APIs, so developers can experiment with new ideas while—in theory—preventing their experiments from being relied upon and then breaking web developers' code during the standardization process. Developers should wait to include the unprefixed property until browser behavior is standardized.

— [source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Vendor_Prefix)